# Knife Tool is stuck to the origin of the geometry of the object

Tags: knife-tool

The Knife tool is stuck to the origin of the object. I hover all over the vertices and edges, and nothing. There is nothing inside of that object, no hidden vertex, it's literally the origin.

I tried it on all of my objects in the file, and they all have the same problem, but when I open a new file, the Knife Tool works just fine. I can't find the answer anywhere else, so the only way to continue is to copy paste everything I have in that Blender file to a new one in order for it to work again.

---

**System Information**

- Operating system: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0 64 Bits
- Graphics card: GeForce GTX 1060/PCIe/SSE2 NVIDIA Corporation 4.5.0 NVIDIA 457.30

I am using Blender Version 2.91

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share the bad file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ?

Comment: Done and done. Thanks for responding btw

Comment: NP. Suspected it, found it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your View clipping range in the 3D View in the 'bad' file, is enormous, so the depth calculation for point-picking in the viewport is beyond floating-point resolution.

In the 'View' tab of the <kbd>N</kbd> sidebar, set the Clip Start and Clip End to values that are enough to comfortably accommodate your scene, but no more.

A visual clue that this is happening is 'shards' appearing in shaded surfaces, like Z-fighting, even though the surfaces interfering with one another are not coincident.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I tried it, and I can use the knife tool again. Once again, thank you so much for the help.