# Glitch see-through faces

Tags: artifacts

Help. Most of my faces glitches out when i orbit or move around. The floor grid also disappears if i zoom too far. My normal are facing the right way
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the "glitching", please provide a .blend file using [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/).

As for stuff disappearing, I think we can see the culprit on your screenshot:

[image]

An extreme range here is a common problem, try right-clicking on *Clip Start* > *"Reset to Default Value"* then the same for *End*. Or create a new *Layout* workspace and discard the old one.

If this answer helps then this is related: [Knife Tool is stuck to the origin of the geometry of the object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208920/knife-tool-is-stuck-to-the-origin-of-the-geometry-of-the-object)

Comment: Well that works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your object is so huge and big , and you may didn't model it in true scale .

1. Hit tab and go to object mode
2. select your object and Hit "N" and select "Item" tab
3. In the "transform" field under "Dimensions" change Z dimension to something more real like 2 meters or less
4. Under scale Click and drag your mouse on Z scale up to change others scales too (Uniform scaling)
5. apply scale by hitting "ctrl + a"
   also you can smaller your object by hitting "S" but it takes more time:)

Comment: the object is smaller than a blender default cube so i don't think that's the problem